# R (randomForest): ntree = 1 no matter how I change it

Tags: r, random-forest

I ran a random forest classification using the randomForest package. When it is finished, I typed summary() on my classifier and it appeared that the ntree parameter was left equal to 1, when I was told that the default value was 500, and it could be changed manually in the argument of randomForest, which I tried unsuccessfully.

I also tried it with another dataset and I had the same issue. Does anyone has any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Can you show us the code you ran, or better yet, a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/496488)?

Comment: Thanks! The solution was right in front of me. Can't believe didn't try it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** To get a summary of the model, just type the name of the model object. For example, if the model object is `rf1` type `rf1`, not `summary(rf1)`.

---

Most packages have a summary "method" that gets dispatched when you run `summary` on an object produced by the package. But in the case of `randomForest` there doesn't seem to be a summary method. The output of `randomForest` is a list containing a bunch of model output. When you run `summary` on it, it just runs the default `summary` function, which returns the length of each list element, which is not very useful here.

Thus, in this case, when you run `summary` on your `randomForest` model object, you're seeing a value of 1 for `ntree`, because `ntree` is an element of the list returned by `randomForest` and it is a vector of length 1. (Note that the column name of the `summary` output is `Length`.)

To see a summary of model results, just type the name of your model object and this will cause an actual summary to be printed to the console. For example, if your model object is called `rf1`, just type `rf1`, not `summary(rf1)`. Typing the object name causes the `print.randomForest` method to be dispatched, and this does provide a summary of the `randomForest` results, including `ntree`.

If you want to extract the value of `ntree` or other results from your model, run `str(rf1)` to see the structure of the list returned by `randomForest` and also look at the help for `randomForest` for additional information on what's in this list. For example, `rf1$ntree` would return the number of trees in the model.